# Primality tests in OpenSSL library

Tags: algorithm, openssl, primes

I am working with prime numbers. I would like to have an algorithm which would conduct prime test as fast as possible. As far as I know 'SSL' library uses the test and it is pretty good in there.

I tried to find the part with the test in the [OpenSSL source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl). I went through almost every file in source code but found nothing. So, I would appreciate very much if someone helped me to find the part of code with prime test.

Comment: The primality tests are in the Crypto library (`libcrypto`), not the SSL library (`libssl`).

Comment: @jww, can you give me a link to it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenSSL, prime testing uses `BN_is_prime_fasttest_ex()`, which is a part of
[libcrypto](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/3ee3c4d2abeeeadc8d33498d1466a3a8381d286b/crypto/bn/bn_prime.c#L234).

Comment: Do you know which algorithm it uses?

Comment: @Alexey It\`s [Miller-Rabin](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_is_prime_fasttest_ex.html).